# HTTPS proxy tunneling with the ssl module

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, https, tunneling

I'd like to manually (using the [socket](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html) and [ssl](http://docs.python.org/library/ssl.html) modules) make an `HTTPS` request through a proxy which itself uses `HTTPS`.

I can perform the initial `CONNECT` exchange just fine:

```
import ssl, socket

PROXY_ADDR = ("proxy-addr", 443)
CONNECT = "CONNECT example.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n"

sock = socket.create_connection(PROXY_ADDR)
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
sock.sendall(CONNECT)
s = ""
while s[-4:] != "\r\n\r\n":
    s += sock.recv(1)
print repr(s)
```

The above code prints `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established` plus some headers, which is what I expect.  So now I should be ready to make the request, e.g.

```
sock.sendall("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n")
```

but the above code returns

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.<br />
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.<br />
</body></html>
```

This makes sense too, since I still need to do an SSL handshake with the `example.com` server to which I'm tunneling.  However, if instead of immediately sending the `GET` request I say

```
sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
```

to do the handshake with the remote server, then I get an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "so_test.py", line 18, in <module>
    ssl.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 350, in wrap_socket
    suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 118, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ssl.py", line 293, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:480: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
```

So how can I do the SSL handshake with the remote `example.com` server?

EDIT: I'm pretty sure that no additional data is available before my second call to `wrap_socket` because calling `sock.recv(1)` blocks indefinitely.

Comment: my rough guess is that `ssl.wrap_socket` cares for socket connection state. usually you'd create socket, then wrap it, then connect. Here you create socket, connect, then wrap. perhaps ssl is just confused by already-connected underlying socket state. https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/598f977df4f52b1d778a40cf4243dd93e486a58a/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py#L333

Comment: hey, did you have any luck? I am stuck with the same problem, but also did not find anything...

Answer (score 9):

This should work if the CONNECT string is rewritten as follows:

```
CONNECT = "CONNECT %s:%s HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" % (server, port)
```

Not sure why this works, but maybe it has something to do with the proxy I'm using. Here's an example code:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import socket

def verify_cb(conn, cert, errun, depth, ok):
        return True

server = 'mail.google.com'
port = 443
PROXY_ADDR = ("proxy.example.com", 3128)
CONNECT = "CONNECT %s:%s HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" % (server, port)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(PROXY_ADDR)
s.send(CONNECT)
print s.recv(4096)      

ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER, verify_cb)
ss = SSL.Connection(ctx, s)

ss.set_connect_state()
ss.do_handshake()
cert = ss.get_peer_certificate()
print cert.get_subject()
ss.shutdown()
ss.close()
```

Note how the socket is first opened and then open socket placed in SSL context. Then I manually initialize SSL handshake. And output:

> HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
>
> <X509Name object '/C=US/ST=California/L=Mountain View/O=Google Inc/CN=mail.google.com'>

It's based on pyOpenSSL because I needed to fetch invalid certificates too and Python built-in ssl module will always try to verify the certificate if it's received.

Comment: Does this work for you even if you're connecting to an HTTPS proxy?  In your example, you're connecting to a regular proxy, which also works for me.  It's when I need to double-wrap the socket that it fails.

Comment: Good answer, but why is it not possible to use `ssl.wrap_socket`?

Comment: This does not work as well for the case of HTTPS-over-HTTPS and results in the same error

Comment: I get `Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO', 'unknown protocol')]` and no binary rubbish in ssl depth-1 output. I suspect that instead of wrapping data in SSL twice, OpenSSL reuses the underlying socket/fd and only wraps data once.

Comment: You are not using a HTTPS proxy I think, it's just a HTTPS in HTTP proxy example

Answer (score 5):

Judging from the API of the OpenSSL and GnuTLS library, stacking a SSLSocket onto a SSLSocket is actually not straightforwardly possible as they provide special read/write functions to implement the encryption, which they are not able to use themselves when wrapping a pre-existing SSLSocket.

The error is therefore caused by the inner SSLSocket directly reading from the system socket and not from the outer SSLSocket. This ends in sending data not belonging to the outer SSL session, which ends badly and for sure never returns a valid ServerHello.

Concluding from that, I would say there is no simple way to implement what you (and actually myself) would like to accomplish.

Comment: Sounds like a sound explanation *NPI*. Do you perhaps know an alternative?

Comment: Sadly not, if you have any idea, I am all ears

Comment: I got somewhere looping data back through `socket.socketpair` ;-)

Comment: @qarma so you read it from the SSLSocket, write it into the socketpair and then read again from the second SSLSocket on the other end of the socketpair?!

Comment: Yep that's basically it. Meanwhile I discovered that `twisted` package appears to support SSL-in-SSL via custom `BIO` in its SSL/TLS module, but that's a lot of dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got somewhere expanding on @kravietz and @02strich answers.

Here's the code

```
import threading
import select
import socket
import ssl

server = 'mail.google.com'
port = 443
PROXY = ("localhost", 4433)
CONNECT = "CONNECT %s:%s HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" % (server, port)


class ForwardedSocket(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, s, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dest = s
        self.oursraw, self.theirsraw = socket.socketpair(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.theirs = socket.socket(_sock=self.theirsraw)
        self.start()
        self.ours = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(_sock=self.oursraw), **kwargs)

    def run(self):
        rl, wl, xl = select.select([self.dest, self.theirs], [], [], 1)
        print rl, wl, xl
        # FIXME write may block
        if self.theirs in rl:
            self.dest.send(self.theirs.recv(4096))
        if self.dest in rl:
            self.theirs.send(self.dest.recv(4096))

    def recv(self, *args):
        return self.ours.recv(*args)

    def send(self, *args):
        return self.outs.recv(*args)


def test():
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(PROXY)
    s = ssl.wrap_socket(s, ciphers="ALL:aNULL:eNULL")
    s.send(CONNECT)
    resp = s.read(4096)
    print (resp, )

    fs = ForwardedSocket(s, ciphers="ALL:aNULL:eNULL")
    fs.send("foobar")
```

Don't mind custom `cihpers=`, that only because I didn't want to deal with certificates.

And there's depth-1 ssl output, showing `CONNECT`, my response to it `ssagd` and depth-2 ssl negotiation and binary rubbish:

```
[dima@bmg ~]$ openssl s_server  -nocert -cipher "ALL:aNULL:eNULL"
Using default temp DH parameters
Using default temp ECDH parameters
ACCEPT
-----BEGIN SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
MHUCAQECAgMDBALAGQQgmn6XfJt8ru+edj6BXljltJf43Sz6AmacYM/dSmrhgl4E
MOztEauhPoixCwS84DL29MD/OxuxuvG5tnkN59ikoqtfrnCKsk8Y9JtUU9zuaDFV
ZaEGAgRSnJ81ogQCAgEspAYEBAEAAAA=
-----END SSL SESSION PARAMETERS-----
Shared ciphers: [snipped]
CIPHER is AECDH-AES256-SHA
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
CONNECT mail.google.com:443 HTTP/1.0
Connection: close

sagq
�u\�0�,�(�$��
�"�!��kj98���� �m:��2�.�*�&���=5�����
��/�+�'�#��     ����g@32��ED���l4�F�1�-�)�%���</�A������
                                                        ��      ������
                                                                      �;��A��q�J&O��y�l
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't sound like there's anything wrong with what you're doing; it's certainly possible to call `wrap_socket()` on an existing `SSLSocket`.

The 'unknown protocol' error can occur (amongst other reasons) if there's extra data waiting to be read on the socket at the point you call `wrap_socket()`, for instance an extra `\r\n` or an HTTP error (due to a missing cert on the server end, for instance). Are you certain you've read everything available at that point?

If you can force the first SSL channel to use a "plain" RSA cipher (i.e. non-Diffie-Hellman) then you may be able to use Wireshark to decrypt the stream to see what's going on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there's nothing available on the socket, because if I call `sock.recv(1)` then it blocks indefinitely.  However, thanks for confirming that I can double-wrap a socket.  I can't change the server's SSL settings, though I appreciate the Wireshark suggestion - please let me know if you have any other ideas.

Comment: Do what SimonJ says. 1) SSL sockets work differently then regular sockets. Even if there is raw received SSL data none of it will be returned until a complete and *valid* SSL record is received. 2) You do not need to change anything at the server to force RSA, simply modify the client ciphersuites to exclude any that use diffie-hellman. Of course you'll also need to get the server's private key to decrypt so if you can't get that then all you can see is cipher. Wireshark gives you ground truth: give it a try.

Comment: Can the client connect directly to the server using SSL? It may be that your network topology doesn't allow this, but it'd be good to confirm there's not some protocol-level mismatch (SSL version or cipher suite incompatibility) that's preventing the endpoints from communicating.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @kravietz answer. Here is a version that works in Python3 through a Squid proxy:

```
from OpenSSL import SSL
import socket

def verify_cb(conn, cert, errun, depth, ok):
        return True

server = 'mail.google.com'
port = 443
PROXY_ADDR = ("<proxy_server>", 3128)
CONNECT = "CONNECT %s:%s HTTP/1.0\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" % (server, port)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(PROXY_ADDR)
s.send(str.encode(CONNECT))
s.recv(4096)

ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
ctx.set_verify(SSL.VERIFY_PEER, verify_cb)
ss = SSL.Connection(ctx, s)

ss.set_connect_state()
ss.do_handshake()
cert = ss.get_peer_certificate()
print(cert.get_subject())
ss.shutdown()
ss.close()
```

This works in Python 2 also.